# Distribution of users on dates

Tags: algorithm, math

I have some troubles finding the best algorithm for this problem:

I have a set of dates where an activity is available and a set of users that should attend that activity. For every date, I know which users could attend the activity. I would like to find the best selection of dates that permits to every user to attend the activity and to minimize the number of dates.

Until this point is very simple, I simply extract for every user the date where the number of users is larger.

But I have an additional problem: I would like to limit the maximum number of users for a date. So for example, on a particular date I could have 30 users, but I dedice to limit the number to 20. So I have to move 10 users on different dates. The problem is actually this, moving the 10 users that will create the best solution on the different dates.

Do You have any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot,
Marco

Comment: maybe the Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm for Maximum Flow Problem could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, this is a Nurse rostering problem (NP-hard).

Solutions to the problem use a variety of techniques, including both mathematically exact solutions and a variety of heuristic solutions using decomposition, parallel computing, stochastic optimization, genetic algorithms, colony optimization, simulated annealing, Tabu search, and coordinate descent.